# Nepali language copy paste issue

Tags: string, android-studio, ms-word

I have a word doc with Nepali translation for an app I am working on.

The word doc looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cQ87.png).

When I try to copy paste the Nepali string, I can't paste the correct string.
Something like this gets copied :-
kIf3ftsf] lrGxx? s] x'g <

I know it's because of the font issue but is there any fix for this ?
I want to copy paste the exact same string into android studio but I can't even copy the exact same string in google translate or browser. It changes into gibberish.

Comment: Maybe the best approach will be to report the issue to Google. See [Android Studio - Report a Bug](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html).

Comment: This question can also apply to the general category. How to copy paste a foreign character string correctly ?

Comment: I speak Catalan and Spanish, and both languages special characters work fine (like à á ü ç...). Maybe you can try to change the font from the default one in the IDE to something like Noto ("International characters Roboto") or some similar font. With that you will know if it's just the font, or there is some additional problem in the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced the same problem.
What you can do is you can add the Nepali font by this method.

```java
TextView tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/nepali.TTF");
tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

Just copy the font in assets folder and copy the Nepali translation in the text box after building the APK the translation will work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a English to Nepali translation for an Android app. I received the Nepali text in a word doc. I have the same problem that you mentioned. The word font is Preeti, and Android Studio needs unicode, which word calls Mangal in this case. I found this tool to convert. You can paste the results directly into your Nepali strings.xml.

https://www.ashesh.com.np/preeti-unicode/

before:
;]e ug'{xf];\ / aGb ug'{xf];\

after:
सेभ गर्नुहोस् र बन्द गर्नुहोस्